# Funnel chart in css

Tags: html, css, charts

I am trying to customize a funnel chart on the basis of data that I have rendered through database on page. 
All works well except css rendering for chart.

```
    <ul id="funnel-cht">
<li style="height:70px;width:50%;background-color:yellow">pendora</li>
<li style="height:70px;width:40%;background-color:#98bf26">pending</li>
<li style="height:70px;width:30%;background-color:orange">pen</li>
<li style="height:70px;width:20%;background-color:#c10000">Test</li>
</ul>
```

Here is what it looks like right now-
http://jsfiddle.net/m74ets8v/1/

I want to style it according to actual looking funnel chart, for an example-
[image]

How would i be styling this chart to make sense for me.

Comment: Do you mean you want the rectangular elements to be centered, or do you want them to be trapezoids?

Comment: @lxg, trapezoids exactly, If i am not saying it wrong then it should be like trapezoid till the width of bottom child.

Comment: Could you please update your question with that information? Right now, it's not clear in how far you want your code to be like the image. And, besides, I'm afraid you'll have to use SVG for that, I don't think there's a way with plain HTML/CSS. (I'm not a CSS guru, however.)

Comment: @lxg, If it fits centered by the parent `li`'s position then also it is okay for me. Currently i am not even able to fit the child centered to its parent and with SVG I am afraid too.

Comment: there's no float:center; property in CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.funnel_outer{width:420px;float: left;position: relative;padding:0 10%;}
.funnel_outer *{box-sizing:border-box}
 .funnel_outer ul{margin:0;padding:0;}
 .funnel_outer ul li{float: left;position: relative;margin:2px 0;height: 50px;clear: both;text-align: center;width:100%;list-style:none}
 .funnel_outer li span{ border-top-width: 50px;border-top-style:  solid; border-left: 25px solid transparent; border-right:25px solid transparent; height: 0;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle; } 
 .funnel_step_1 span{width:100%;border-top-color: #8080b6;}
 .funnel_step_2 span{width:calc(100% - 50px);border-top-color: #669966}
 .funnel_step_3 span{width:calc(100% - 100px);border-top-color: #a27417}
 .funnel_step_4 span{width:calc(100% - 150px);border-top-color: #ff66cc}
 .funnel_step_5 span{width:calc(100% - 200px);border-top-color: #0099ff}
 .funnel_step_6 span{width:calc(100% - 250px);border-top-color: #027002}
 .funnel_step_7 span{width:calc(100% - 300px);border-top-color: #ff0000;}
.funnel_outer ul li:last-child span{border-left: 0;border-right: 0;border-top-width: 40px;}
.funnel_outer ul li.not_last span{border-left: 5px  solid transparent;border-right:5px  solid transparent;border-top-width:50px;}
  .funnel_outer ul li span p{margin-top: -30px;color:#fff;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;}
```

```html
 <div class="funnel_outer">
   <ul>
    <li class="funnel_step_1"><span><p>1</p></span></li>
    <li class="funnel_step_2"><span><p>2</p></span> </li>
    <li class="funnel_step_3"><span><p>3</p></span></li>
    <li class="funnel_step_4"><span><p>4</p></span></li>
    <li class="funnel_step_5"><span><p>5</p></span></li>
    <li class="funnel_step_6"><span><p>6</p></span></li>
    <li class="funnel_step_7"><span><p>7</p></span></li>
 
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret is to use `margin: 0 auto` for the `li`s. Setting the automatic margin calculation for the  left/right dimension will center a block element horizontally. (Unfortunately, this technique doesn't work for vertical centering, but that's a different story.)

Here's your code, slightly modified, in a working example:

```css
ul, li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
ul { width: 400px; }
li { height: 70px; margin: 0 auto; }

/* NOTE: nth-child would be the better way to assign CSS to a set of
   uniform elements than one class per li, but let's keep it simple for now */

li.li1 { width: 50%; background-color: yellow; }
li.li2 { width: 40%; background-color: #98bf26; }
li.li3 { width: 30%; background-color: orange; }
li.li4 { width: 20%; background-color: #c10000; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='li1'>pendora</li>
  <li class='li2'>pending</li>
  <li class='li3'>pen</li>
  <li class='li4'>Test</li>
</ul>
```

By the way, as already noted in the comments: In order to have actual trapezoids, you would (as far as I know) need to use SVG, and of course appropriate fallbacks for browser that don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

If, as i read from comments, you just need to center the `<li>` elements you can set the an auto margin.

```
#funnel-cht>li
{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```